# Lag in reading additional info after Process creation event in WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

I am trying to create an app which monitors for process creation/termination and logs the amount of time it executed and its frequency which is finally being logged in mysql db. The problem that I am facing is that, I am using **Win32_ProcessStartTrace** and **Win32_ProcessStopTrace** for monitoring. As soon a process is created, its commandline is being queried using Win32_Process. ***There seems to be a "lag" between Process creation and the querying of its commandline*** for those processes which exit quickly so I can't get the commandline.

Is there any way of getting this done?

Comment: Are you using a WMI event consumer?

Comment: Actually I'm new to WMI, so in .Net I'm using ManagementEventWatcher and it is Generating an Event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code watches for new processes starting and prints the command line used:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Test().Run();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    internal class Test
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            ProcessWatcher procWatcher = new ProcessWatcher();
            procWatcher.Start();
        }

        private class ProcessWatcher : ManagementEventWatcher
        {
            private const string wql = 
                   @"SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1
                     WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'";

            public ProcessWatcher()
            {
                this.Query.QueryLanguage = "WQL";
                this.Query.QueryString = wql;
                this.EventArrived += newProcessStarted;
            }

            private void newProcessStarted(object sender, 
                                           EventArrivedEventArgs e)
            {
                var process = e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"] 
                              as ManagementBaseObject;

                if (process != null)
                {
                    var cmdLine = process.Properties["CommandLine"].Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(cmdLine);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just updated it - I had the wrong query, it should look for __InstanceCreationEvent..

Comment: I was going to  post it... I used _InstanceCreationEvent ;)

Comment: Powershell oneliner--`Register-WmiEvent -query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'" -SourceIdentifier "GetLaunchArgs" -Action { Write-Host $Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.CommandLine }`

Comment: Note that it will miss short-lived processes.